# Can't open up Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Navigator on a MAC

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, electron, anaconda, jupyter

[Error that pops up when opening Anaconda Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yhfv.png)

I am pretty sure the reason why I can't open up Jupyter Notebook is because I am using a 2012 Macbook Pro that can't update its macOS version any further.

Anaconda Navigator is able to open however when I try opening up Jupyter Notebook I receive the following and nothing else: [Terminal Screen when attempting to open Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UghMr.png)

If there is a work around to open up Jupyter Notebook please share!

I went through the steps of this website: [https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-fix-the-issue-of-jupyter-notebook-not-launching-from-anaconda-navigator/#:~:text=Check%20the%20environment-,If%20there%20is%20an%20issue%20with%20your%20Anaconda%20environment%2C%20Jupyter,from%20the%20drop%2Ddown%20menu](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-fix-the-issue-of-jupyter-notebook-not-launching-from-anaconda-navigator/#:%7E:text=Check%20the%20environment-,If%20there%20is%20an%20issue%20with%20your%20Anaconda%20environment%2C%20Jupyter,from%20the%20drop%2Ddown%20menu).

I read through this forum and am working on downgrading Jupyter Notebook to another version:
[Jupyter notebook not launching from Anaconda Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300930/jupyter-notebook-not-launching-from-anaconda-navigator)

I noticed I didn't have the following path: '/Users/your-name/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/notebook.sh' so I am not sure if that could be the root cause.

Last thing I haven't done was uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: Did you replace You-Name in the path with you user

Comment: Yes. I ended up downgrading the version of JupterNotebook to 5.0.0 and it worked!